# Django: Testing locally before pushing app to Heroku

Tags: django, git, heroku

I've followed the instructions from Heroku's "[Getting Started with Django](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django)", and successfully deployed my application on the Heroku server.

However, there wasn't any tutorial on how to test my application locally before committing and pushing any change on my codes. For example, after I make some minor changes on my css file or Django views, I want to test it on my local computer first, instead of having to do "git push heroku master" every time..

How do I do this with Heroku?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To test your app locally you don't need to use Heroku. Simply go to the folder where your `manage.py` is and do:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

It will fire up a development web server with your app you can access using the following URL in your browser: *http://localhost:8000*.

This web server reloads automatically when you make changes to the Python code. See the Django tutorial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/#the-development-server

Additionally, you might need to set some variables in your environment (`export VARNAME=value`) to make it work with 12-factor-style settings.